# Apache webdav login works on browsers, but error on net use command / window explorer

Tags: windows, apache, amazon-ec2, webdav

I would like to set up a simple WebDAV service on my server, which runs on Linux (Amazon EC2) and provide users to save files and folders.

After config-ed some files, I manage to get the service running with the config below:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/webdav/
        ServerName webdav.example.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined

        Alias /user1 /var/www/html/users/user1
        <Directory /var/www/html/users/user1>
            DirectoryIndex disabled
            Options Indexes MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            DAV On
            AuthType Digest
            AuthName "user1"
            AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
            Require valid-user

            # Force not to render PHP files and make all files to plain text 
            RemoveHandler .php
            ForceType text/plain
            php_flag engine off
        </Directory>

        # Lets Encrypt's SSL stuff
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/webdav.example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/webdav.example.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

After restart the httpd service, when I navigate to `https://webdav.example.com/user1` in either Google Chrome or Firefox, I am able to login (with a prompt) dialog asking for username/password. With the corrected username/password entered, I am able to get a list of files, as expected.

**However**, when I would like to set up the Network drive in Windows explorer, or via command `net use u: https://webdav.example.com/user1`, I keep getting the error:

```
System error 67 has occurred. 

The network name cannot be found.
```

I have tested on multiple Windows machine (all are up-to-date Windows 10 1803) and all of them have the same error.

Any helps would be appreciated.